# Can sauerkraut be prepared with open lid?

Tags: sauerkraut

If the cabbage is successfully kept with weight, under the brine, all the time.

I use a glass paper weight as weight. Can mold also form on the weight, on the portion which remain above the brine while using a closed lid or an open lid?

Thanks.

Comment: On *glass*? Highly unlikely when you make sure it's clean (obvious contamination would be from your hands)

Answer (score 2):

Making sauerkraut does not require a lid.  As long as the cabbage is submerged (and you have the proper brine) it will be fine.  Any mold that forms on the surface or the weight can be removed.

Comment: Then what is the reason, most people and internet, tell to use close lid or airlock jar. My knowledge and as you said, as long the cabbage is submerged under the brine, sauerkraut should be prepared successfully. Because bad bacteria or mold shouldn't form under the brine. Also in an open environment, the gas formed can easily escape, which doesn't happen in a closed jar.

Comment: @RajeshMarndi don't know.  I've never covered.  I use a food grade, plastic, rectangular, 7.5L Cambro container for my veg. and brine.  I weigh it down with a water-filled smaller Cambro, which fits inside.  No cover necessary.

Answer (score -1):

When I made it, I found you need to remove some moldy bits from anything on the surface whether the cabbage touches the surface of not.

Comment: You are not answering the question if mold can form on the glass weight. And the OP already wrote that the cabbage is fully submerged.